# Deployment issue after changing the file extension in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor

I migrated some views to Razor (cshtml) from Webforms (aspx) by changing the file extension and then fixing the syntactic differences. Now when deploying, the app can no longer find the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the visual studio build actions ... maybe something changed when you renamed the file